# Does the ratio of the mechanical degrees of a generator to 360 degrees have a specific term and symbol?

Tags: generator

When it comes to DC generators, the ratio of the mechanical degrees of a generator between two brushes to the total mechanical degrees which is always 360 is used in different quantities such as demagnetizing turns per pole. This ratio can also be expressed through other means, such as stating the number of commutator segments or through the length of an arc and the circumference. I just want to know if this quantity has a formal symbol and name.

[image]

For reference, this was taken from Page 941 of Electrical Technology by Theraja. It shows one usage of the ratio I was mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If \$\theta_m\$ is given in degrees, then \$\frac{\theta_m}{360}\$ is the angle given in (fractional) "turns".
If \$\theta_m\$ is given in radians, then \$\frac{\theta_m}{2\pi}\$ would be the angle given in (fractional) turns.
In either case, the \$360\$ or \$2\pi\$ is simply a factor to convert from degrees (or radians) to (fractional) turns.
However, note that the (fractional) "turns" in this case, is simply a way to  describe an angle, not the number of electrical winding turns.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn_(angle)

Comment: Yes, I want to know if that "fractional turns" can be considered a formal name and would have a symbol associated for it even if the name and symbol are not that common? Because when I look deeply for some other obscure quantities like the pole arc and pole pitch ratio, they do have a symbol and name.

Comment: Please read the Wikipedia article. The term "turn" is standard, and a legal term of measurment in some countries. However, there is no agreed upon symbol. If the definition of \$\theta_m\$ was described as "mechanical angle in turns", then you could simply omit the 360. However, most Americans are far more familiar with angles being measured by degrees, and are likely to be confused by turns, milliturns, microturns etc.